# How can I make a Javascript clickable event for mouse/tap users hidden from keyboard users?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have a website navigation that pops out from the side when a button is activated on small screens using a Javascript function that works with clicks, taps or space/enter key strokes. It works like a modal and a keyboard user is trapped in the pop-out navigation until they close the menu either by using the space/enter key on the 'close menu' button or by using the Escape key or by clicking a link, at which point the trapping code is reversed.

I have created a mouse/tap event for non-keyboard users so that if the user clicks or taps outside the modal/pop-out, rather than on the 'close menu' button, the navigation pop-out closes and all trapping code is also reversed.

However, on using the Accessibility checker in Firefox I get this message: "Focusable elements should have interactive semantics". Is there a way to disguise the event from keyboard users?

This is the JavaScript:

```
content.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let sidenavO = openSidenav.querySelector('sidenav-opened');
    if ((e.target != menuBtn) && (sidenavO.className ='sidenav-opened')){
    hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');
    closeMenuWithClick();
    }
})
```

Here is the full HTML, CSS and JavaScript:

```js
/* detect keyboard users */
function handleFirstTab(e) {
    if (e.key === "Tab") { // the "I am a keyboard user" key
        document.body.classList.add('user-is-tabbing');
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab);

function closeAllHandler(e){
// esc key
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
        let openItems = document.querySelectorAll("button.opened");
        for(var x = 0; x < openItems.length; x++){
        openItems[x].classList.remove('opened');
        }
    let closeSidenav = document.querySelector('sidenav.opened');
    closeSidenav.classList.remove('opened');
    }
}

// Main menu
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
for (const selector of [".btn-level-1", ".btn-level-2", ".btn-level-3", ".btn-level-4", ".btn-level-5", ".btn-level-6",]) {
    const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    for (const button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            buttons.filter(b => b !== button).forEach(b => {
            b.classList.remove('opened');
            b.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
            b.querySelector('span.v-open-icon').innerHTML = "+";
            b.querySelector('span.h-open-icon').innerHTML = "▼";
            b.querySelector('.toggleText').innerHTML = "Show submenu";
            });
        button.classList.toggle('opened');
        let ariaExpanded = button.classList.contains('opened').toString();
        button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", ariaExpanded);
        let vstr = button.querySelector('.v-open-icon');
            if (vstr.innerHTML === "+") {
                vstr.innerHTML = "–";
            } else {
                vstr.innerHTML = "+";
            }
        let hstr = button.querySelector('.h-open-icon');
            if (hstr.innerHTML === "▼") {
                hstr.innerHTML = "▲";
            } else {
                hstr.innerHTML = "▼";
            }
        let toggle = button.querySelector('span span.toggleText');
            if (toggle.innerHTML === "Show submenu") {
                toggle.innerHTML = "Close submenu";
            } else {
                toggle.innerHTML = "Show submenu";
            }
        })
    }}

// When clicking outside the menu, this closes all sub-menus by removing all instances of the 'opened' class
    document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (!e.target.closest('.menucontent')) {
            let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".opened");
            [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
            el.className = el.className.replace(/\bopened\b/, "");
            })
            let vicons = document.querySelectorAll(".v-open-icon");
            [].forEach.call(vicons, function(vi) {
            vi.innerHTML = vi.innerHTML.replace("–", "+");
            })
            let hicons = document.querySelectorAll(".h-open-icon");
            [].forEach.call(hicons, function(hi) {
            hi.innerHTML = hi.innerHTML.replace("▲", "▼");
            })
            let subm = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleText");
            [].forEach.call(subm, function(sub) {
            sub.innerHTML = sub.innerHTML.replace("Close submenu", "Open submenu");
            })
        }
    });
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
            let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".opened");
            [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
            el.className = el.className.replace(/\bopened\b/, "");
            })
            let vicons = document.querySelectorAll(".v-open-icon");
            [].forEach.call(vicons, function(vi) {
            vi.innerHTML = vi.innerHTML.replace("–", "+");
            })
            let hicons = document.querySelectorAll(".h-open-icon");
            [].forEach.call(hicons, function(hi) {
            hi.innerHTML = hi.innerHTML.replace("▲", "▼");
            })
            let subm = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleText");
            [].forEach.call(subm, function(sub) {
            sub.innerHTML = sub.innerHTML.replace("Close submenu", "Open submenu");
            })
        }
    });
//);
/////////////////////////////////////////HIDING ALL OTHER CONTENT FROM SCREEN READERS///////////////////////////////////
let content = document.querySelector('.outerwrap');
let menuBtn = document.querySelector('.trigram');
let closeMenuBtn = document.querySelector('.closenavbtn');
let openSidenav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
let menu = document.getElementById('vmenu').querySelector('div.menucontent');
let focusableItems = ['a[href]', 'area[href]', 'input:not([disabled])', 'select:not([disabled])', 'iframe:not([disabled])', 'textarea:not([disabled])', 'button:not([disabled])', '[tabindex]:not([disabled])', '[contenteditable=true]:not([disabled])'];

//the main function for setting the tabindex to -1 for all children of a parent with given ID (and reversing the process)
function hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems(outerwrap){

//build a query string that targets the parent div ID and all children elements that are in our focusable items list.
let queryString = "";
for (i = 0, leni = focusableItems.length; i < leni; i++) {
    queryString += "." + outerwrap + " " + focusableItems[i] + ", " || "button.gotop.top-link" + ", ";
}
queryString = queryString.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
    
    let focusableElements = document.querySelectorAll(queryString);
    for (j = 0, lenj = focusableElements.length; j < lenj; j++) {

        let el = focusableElements[j];
        if (!el.hasAttribute('data-modified')) { // we use the 'data-modified' attribute to track all items that we have applied a tabindex to (as we can't use tabindex itself).

        // we haven't modified this element so we grab the tabindex if it has one and store it for use later when we want to restore.
            if(el.hasAttribute('tabindex')){
                el.setAttribute('data-oldTabIndex', el.getAttribute('tabindex'));
            }

            el.setAttribute('data-modified', true);
            el.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'); // add `tabindex="-1"` to all items to remove them from the focus order.

            } 
        else if (((screen.width >= 768) && (el.hasAttribute('data-modified'))) || (el.hasAttribute('data-modified'))) {
            //we have modified this item so we want to revert it back to the original state it was in.
            el.removeAttribute('tabindex');
            if(el.hasAttribute('data-oldtabindex')) {
                el.setAttribute('tabindex', el.getAttribute('data-oldtabindex'));
                el.removeAttribute('data-oldtabindex');
            }
            el.removeAttribute('data-modified');
        }
    }
}

let globalLets = {};

function openMenu(){
    menu.classList.add("menu-b");
    menu.classList.remove("menu-a");
    openSidenav.className ='sidenav-opened';
    openSidenav.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
    menuBtn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
    
    //get all the focusable items in our menu and keep track of the button that opened the menu for when we close it again.
     setFocus(menuBtn, 'menu');
    
    content.setAttribute("aria-hidden", true);
}

function closeMenu(){
    //close menu
    //unhide the main content
    content.removeAttribute("aria-hidden");
    //hide the menu
    menu.classList.add("menu-a");
    menu.classList.remove("menu-b");
    openSidenav.className ='sidenav';
    // set `aria-expanded` - important for screen reader users.
    menuBtn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
    openSidenav.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
    //set focus back to the button that opened the menu if we can
    if (globalLets.beforeOpen) {
        globalLets.beforeOpen.focus();
    }
}

//toggle the menu
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
//use our function to add the relevant `tabindex="-1"` to all interactive elements outside of the menu.
hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');
//check if the menu is open, if it is close it and reverse everything.
openMenu();
});

closeMenuBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
//use our function to add the relevant `tabindex="-1"` to all interactive elements outside of the menu.
hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');
//check if the menu is open, if it is close it and reverse everything.
closeMenu();
});

window.addEventListener('resize', wideScreen);
function wideScreen() {
    let ww = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
    if (ww.matches) {
        let outer = document.querySelector('.outerwrap');
        if (outer.hasAttribute("aria-hidden", true)) { 
        hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');
        closeMenu();
        }
    }
}
//////////////////////// CLOSE SIDENAV WITH CLICK /////////////////////////////

function closeMenuWithClick() {
    closeMenu();
}
let shadowwrapper = document.querySelector('.shadowwrapper');
//this one affects 'outerwrap' function whether sidenav opened or not
 shadowwrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let sidenavO = openSidenav.querySelectorAll('.sidenav-opened');
    if ((e.target != menuBtn) && (sidenavO.className ='sidenav-opened')){
    hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');
    closeMenuWithClick();
    }
})

//////////////////////////////////TRAPPING FOCUS//////////////////////////////////

let setFocus = function (item, className) { //we pass in the button that activated the menu and the className of the menu list, your menu must have a unique className for this to work.

    className = "sidenav-opened"; //defaults to class 'content' in case of error ("content" being the class on the <main> element.)
    globalLets.beforeOpen = item; //we store the button that was pressed before the modal opened in a global letiable so we can return focus to it on modal close.

    let findItems = [];
    for (i = 0, len = focusableItems.length; i < len; i++) {
        findItems.push('.' + className + " " + focusableItems[i]); //add every focusable item to an array.
    }
    // finally add the open button to our list of focusable items as it sits outside our menu list. 
    
    let findString = findItems.join(", ");
    globalLets.canFocus = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(findString)); 
    if (globalLets.canFocus.length > 0) {
        globalLets.canFocus[0].focus(); //***set the focus to the first focusable element within the modal
        globalLets.lastItem = globalLets.canFocus[globalLets.canFocus.length - 1]; //we also store the last focusable item within the modal so we can keep focus within the modal. 
    }
}

//listen for keypresses and intercept both the Esc key (to close the menu) and tab and shift tab while the menu is open so we can manage focus.
 document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.key === "Escape") {
        //unhide the main content - exactly the same as in the btn event listener.
        hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');
        closeMenu();
    }
}
```

```css
:root {
  --dark-green: #297924;
  --light-green: #61A25B;
  --gold: #9B6E03;
  --dark-grey: #515151;
  --med-dark-grey: #737573;
  --medium-grey: #9c9c9f;
  --light-grey: #d8d8db;
  --lightest-grey: #3c3333;
  --link-blue: #0c6dd4;
}
div, button, li, [class^="col-"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.container-fluid,
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.row-fluid,
.row{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.shadowwrapper {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ABCDA8;
  padding: 0 16px;
  min-height: 800px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
 .shadowwrapper{ 
    box-shadow: 0 5px 7px 7px rgba(184, 185, 190, 0.80);
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
 .shadowwrapper { 
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 1332px;
  }
}
body.user-is-tabbing button > a:focus {
  border: none;
}
body:not(.user-is-tabbing) a:focus,
body:not(.user-is-tabbing) button:focus,
body:not(.user-is-tabbing) input:focus,
body:not(.user-is-tabbing) select:focus,
body:not(.user-is-tabbing) textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.top-link {
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 1rem;
  color: white;
  background: var(--dark-green);
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.top-link:hover {
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: var(--light-green);
}
.menu{
display: none;
}
.menu.open{
  display: block;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
main {
  min-height: 800px;
}
.menu-outer{
  border-top: 1px solid var(--dark-green);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--dark-green);
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.75rem;
}
.md-menu-outer {
  border-top: 2px solid var(--dark-green);
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--dark-green);
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.75rem;
}
.trigram {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 995;
  width: 2rem;
}
.burger {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 0.15rem solid var(--dark-green);
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 0.15rem solid var(--dark-green);
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
}
.burger::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-top: 0.15rem solid var(--dark-green);
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2rem;
}
.sidenav {
  display: none;
}
.sidenav-opened {
  transition: width 0.5s;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 996;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 1rem 0 0
}
.closenavbtn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--dark-green);
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 2rem;
  z-index: 998;
}
.closenavbtn a {
  color: var(--dark-green);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.main-menu-container {
  display: none;
}
.sidemenu {
  padding: 5rem 1rem 1rem;
}
.mm .has-submenu> div.ul {
  display: none;
}
.mm .has-submenu> div.ul.open {
  display: block;
}
.mm .menu-toggle {
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.mm {
  min-height: 1.5rem;
}
.mm .menucontent.menu-a,
.mm .menucontent.menu-a {
  list-style: none;
}
.mm .menucontent.menu-a {
  display: none;
}
.mm .menucontent.menu-b {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: normal;
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 997;
  overflow-y: auto;
  }
.mm .li {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
.mm .li > [type="button"] {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mm [type="button"] ~ div.ul {
  display: none;
}
.mm [type="button"].opened ~ div.ul {
  display: table;
  z-index: 99;
}
.mm div[class^="ul level"] {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
}
.mm .li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  border-top: 1px dotted var(--medium-grey);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 44px;
}
.mm .li.single {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}
.mm .menucontent > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted var(--medium-grey);
}
.mm .li.top-level {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.mm .li a,
.mm .li span {
  color: var(--dark-green);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.mm .li a {
  padding: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0.25rem;
}
.mm .li.top-level > span {
  padding: 0;
}
.mm .li a {
  padding: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0.25rem;
}
.mm span.v-open-icon {
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
}
.mm button.linked span.v-open-icon {
  padding: 0 0 0.25rem 1rem;
}
.mm .li.active > a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.mm [type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  min-width: 44px;
  min-height: 44px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  top: 0;
}
.mm [type="button"]:not(:disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mm .li.separator:hover > span,
.mm .li.heading:hover > span,
.mm .li > a:hover,
.mm button.linked:hover > span {
color: var(--gold);
}
.user-is-tabbing a:focus,
.user-is-tabbing .mm .li > .separator:focus > span,
.user-is-tabbing .mm .li > .heading:focus > span,
.user-is-tabbing .mm .li > a:focus,
.user-is-tabbing .mm .li > button.linked:focus > span {
color: #f0f;
}
.user-is-tabbing div.outerwrap:focus {
  outline: #f0f;
}
.mm .li.top-level > span.v-open-icon {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.mm .li .h-open-icon {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .trigram,
  .trigramborder,
  .sidenav,
  .sidenav-opened {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
  }
  .closebtn {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .menu-outer {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-menu-container {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  .main-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .mm .menucontent.menu-a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
  }
  .mm .menucontent.menu-a,
  .mm .menucontent.menu-b {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .mm div [class^="ul level"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .mm div.ul.level-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #acaaaa;
    padding: 0 0 0.25rem;
  }
  .mm div.ul.level-2 {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .mm .li {
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level {
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    border-right: 1px solid var(--dark-green);
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 2.875rem;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level.parent {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level:last-child {
    border-right: none;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level:last-child > div.ul {
    float: right;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level.single {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  .mm .li.current.active a {
    color: var(--gold);
    font-weight: bold;
  } 
  .mm.top-level {
    white-space: normal;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level a  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 1.5rem;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level > span {
    padding: 0.55rem 0 0.45rem;
  }
  .mm .li.active > a {
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .mm .li a:hover + [type="button"]::after,
  .mm .li [type="button"]:hover::after,  
  .mm .li a:hover {
    color: var(--gold);
    transition: none;
  }
  .mm .menucontent > li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .mm .li .h-open-icon {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.55rem 0 0.45rem 1rem;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level > span.h-open-icon,
  .mm .li[class^="btn-level"] span.h-open-icon {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }
  .mm .li div.ul .li button[class^="btn-level"] > .h-open-icon {
    padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
  }  
  .mm .li.top-level > button > span.h-open-icon {
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  }
  .mm .li .v-open-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level {
    min-width: 6rem;
  }
  .mm .li.top-level {
    min-width: 2.75rem;
  }
}
.visually-hidden { 
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px; 
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidenav" class="sidenav">
    <button class="closenavbtn">&times;</button>
    <div id="vmenu" class="sidemenu mm">
        <nav aria-label="Main Navigation" class="menuouter " role="navigation">
            <div class="ul menucontent menu-a">
                <div class="li item-101 default current active single top-level">
                    <a href="/" title="Home">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="li item-129 divider deeper parent top-level">
                    <button class="separator btn-level-1" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" aria-label="Has sub-menu" title="Has sub-menu">
                    <span class="btpr">Has sub-menu</span>
                    <span class="v-open-icon">+</span>
                    <span class="h-open-icon">▼</span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden"><span class="toggleText">Show submenu</span> for Has sub-menu</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="ul level-1 separator" role="menu">
                        <div class="li item-128 single">
                            <a href="/" title="Link 1">Link 1</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="li item-130 single">
                            <a href="/" title="Link 2">Link 2</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="li item-131 single">
                            <a href="/" title="Link 3">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="li item-132 single">
                            <a href="/" title="Link 4">Link 4</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="li item-136 divider deeper parent">
                            <button class="separator btn-level-2" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" aria-label="Life Events" title="Has another submenu">
                            <span class="btpr">Has another submenu</span>
                            <span class="v-open-icon">+</span>
                            <span class="h-open-icon">▼</span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden"><span class="toggleText">Show submenu</span> for Has another submenu</span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="ul level-2 separator" role="menu">
                                <div class="li item-148 single">
                                    <a href="/" title="Lower Link 1">Lower Link 1</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="li item-150 single">
                                    <a href="/" title="Lower Link 2">Lower Link 2</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="li item-151 single">
                                    <a href="/" title="Lower Link 3">Lower Link 3</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="li item-152 single">
                                    <a href="/" title="Lower Link 4">Lower Link 4</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outerwrap">
    <div class="shadowwrapper" tabindex="-1">
        <header>
            <div><a href="/" title="Home page">Logo here</a></div>
        </header>
        <div class="container-fluid menu-outer">
            <button class="trigram burger" aria-expanded="false"><span class="visually-hidden">Open main navigation</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid md-menu-outer">
            <div class="main-menu-container">
                <div id="hmenu" class="row main-menu mm">
                    <nav aria-label="Main Navigation" class="menuouter " role="navigation">
                        <div class="ul menucontent menu-a">
                            <div class="li item-101 default current active single top-level">
                                <a href="/" title="Home">Home</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="li item-129 divider deeper parent top-level">
                                <button class="separator btn-level-1" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" aria-label="Has sub-menu" title="Has sub-menu">
                                <span class="btpr">Has sub-menu</span>
                                <span class="v-open-icon">+</span>
                                <span class="h-open-icon">▼</span>
                                <span class="visually-hidden"><span class="toggleText">Show submenu</span> for Has sub-menu</span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="ul level-1 separator" role="menu">
                                    <div class="li item-128 single">
                                        <a href="/" title="Link 1">Link 1</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="li item-130 single">
                                        <a href="/" title="Link 2">Link 2</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="li item-131 single">
                                        <a href="/" title="Link 3">Link 3</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="li item-132 single">
                                        <a href="/" title="Link 4">Link 4</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="li item-136 divider deeper parent">
                                        <button class="separator btn-level-2" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" aria-label="Has another sub-menu" title="Has another sub-menu">
                                        <span class="btpr">Has another sub-menu</span>
                                        <span class="v-open-icon">+</span>
                                        <span class="h-open-icon">▼</span>
                                        <span class="visually-hidden"><span class="toggleText">Show submenu</span> for Has another sub-menu</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="ul level-2 separator" role="menu">
                                            <div class="li item-148 single">
                                                <a href="/" title="Lower Link 1">Lower Link 1</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="li item-150 single">
                                                <a href="/" title="Lower Link 2">Lower Link 2</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="li item-151 single">
                                                <a href="/" title="Lower Link 3">Lower Link 3</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="li item-152 single">
                                                <a href="/" title="Lower Link 4">Lower Link 4</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <main>
            <p>Some body content</p>
            <p>Integer justo dui, faucibus dictum, convallis sodales, accumsan id, risus. Aenean risus. </p>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Care to chuck the HTML into your question as well so we can give the best advice. Normally you would structure it so the background is a separate element (a sibling) to the modal so that you can use `aria-hidden` on it. You can then also use `tabindex="-1"` on the background element to stop the error. If you are trapping focus correctly (by using `aria-hidden` on all elements outside of the modal etc. bear in mind screen reader users navigate with shortcuts for headings, links etc. so you can't just listen for `Tab`) then you can safely ignore the warning. Drop your HTML in qn and I will help.

Comment: Ok. I'm adding the full code, which incorporates much of your JS from other posts. Adding `tabindex="-1"` to either the outerwrap div or the child shadowwrapper div makes no difference to Firefox. I've also noticed another problem in that the `hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');` function is executed on click whether or not the sidenav popout has the `sidenav-opened` class.

Comment: I have solved the issue of the `hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');` firing on every click with this revised code: ```let sidenav = document.getElementById('sidenav');
content.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if ((e.target != menuBtn) && (sidenav.matches('.sidenav-opened'))) {
 hideOrShowAllInteractiveItems('outerwrap');
 closeMenuWithClick();
 }
}) ```

Comment: But I still have the original problem of the `outerwrap` accessibility issue. If I add `aria-hidden="true"` in the source code then the main content is never visible to a keyboard user. It is hidden when the popout is opened as part of the trapping code.

Comment: there is a fair bit to look through so can you bear with me for a couple of days? I am busy this weekend but if you can wait until Monday evening I can have a look then.

Comment: Of course I can wait. I am more than grateful that you are able to look at this for me. I have added it with my updated `closeMenuWithClick` script to [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Scrabble96/pen/LYbjwvN) as it's easier to see the code in action and fiddle with it.

Comment: I believe I have done it, by adding the main content click event to the `function openMenu()` like this: `content.addEventListener('click', closeWithClick);` and reversing it with 'remove' in the `function closeMenu()`.

Comment: I will have a look for you shortly and see if everything works as expected. Hopefully there is nothing for me to do as you fixed it yourself :-)